# What is the Default Theme in Xubuntu 12.10

Tags: themes, xubuntu, icons, xfce

I am using OpenSUSE 12.2 and I would like to apply the default look and feel of Xubuntu 12.10.

I would like to know what is the

1. Default desktop theme name
2. Icon set name
3. Default settings of the dock (the dock at the bottom) - how to apply transparency etc
4. What are other general default settings to make it feel like xubuntu.
5. Where can I get xubuntu 12.10 / ubuntu 12.10 wallpapers?
6. What is the mouse icon theme?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

1. The gtk theme is called Greybird: http://shimmerproject.org/project/greybird/
2. Icon set name: elementary Xfce Dark. See
   https://github.com/shimmerproject/elementary-xfce/tree/master/elementary-xfce-dark
3. You could customize a dock in a similar way with cairo-dock, don't know for sure if this works well in kde.
4. Please be more sepecific, it depends on which desktop environment you're using right now. What are you still missing?
5. https://i.stack.imgur.com/HhcNm.jpg
6. The default xfce mouse theme

Comment: Please be more sepecific, install xfce and you'll come a long way -> amm?? what do you mean? I have not installed xfce and still I am asking how to apply xfce themes? Why would I do that?

Comment: You said to be specific=> what are the details I am missing?

Comment: What desktop environment are you using? KDE?

Comment: You can take it as an insult if that is your interpretation, but it's not what I said. First you tell me "I have not installed xfce", now you tell me "I am using a desktop environment called as XFCE". You're saying two contradicting things here. I'm trying to help you here, not make fun of you. So are you running xfce or not? What I understood from you was that you were running a different desktop enviroment and you wanted the Xubuntu look for that enviroment. If you're running XFCE, you can simple download the theme from this [link](https://github.com/shimmerproject/Greybird/tarball/master).